# One maven project using different dependencies in build phase

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I've got a project, name it `project1` and this project contains one `pom.xml`. Now, what I want to achieve is, that I want to specify two different "Profiles" in Eclipse when I run a maven build on the project and then each of the two profiles should use it's own dependencies. For example in build phase `"build_project1_dependency1"` it should use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectX</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

and in the second build phase profile called `"build_project1_dependency2"` it should use the following dependency instead of the first one:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectX</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well what did you try? You can add dependencies in profiles so it sounds like you already have the solution.

Comment: The question is why would you like to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I canno't commet because i'm new here so i'll copy the link.
(i have no idea if it is right or not)

[Maven assembly : add different version of the same artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312553/maven-assembly-add-different-version-of-the-same-artifact)

or you can try this:

[Copy two versions of same jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308366/copy-two-versions-of-same-jar-using-maven)

just search :)